# Foundation 6 Plugins in a React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zurb-foundation

I'm building a React app, using Foundation 6 for my UI. So far this has worked pretty well, but I'm now getting to where I'm changing the markup based on user events instead of just on page load, and the Foundation Plugins aren't working for newly rendered markup.

As a simple example, I've got a Login menu that renders as a Foundation Dropdown. Clicking on an entry in this will, once the user has logged in, cause this to be removed and a different menu to replace it - with the User Profile and the Logout links on it.

My initial attempt simply had `$(document).foundation()` called in the `componentDidMount` method of the top level UI. This worked great for everything rendered in the initial page load, but doesn't pick up anything rendered later on.

I've just tried replacing this with a MutationObserver, and again this works perfectly for anything rendered in the initial page load, but when the menu changes I instead get: "Tried to initialize dropdown-menu on an element that already has a Foundation plugin" - despite this being rendered inside a different React Component.

Is there a correct way to get this to work?